# Mongo connection terminates early unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, node-mongodb-native

I have a NodeJS application that connects to a Mongo database and queries a collection that returns roughly 1.3 million documents. Once a document has been processed (in this case, it is uploaded to an AWS CloudSearch domain), it is marked as processed so that it won't be returned in future queries.

I am using a stream to read the query response and what I'm observing is that only a portion of the documents I am expecting are being read - i.e. if I have 1.3 million documents left to process then only ~80,000 are being processed every time my application is run. If I had say 100,000 documents left to process, only ~10,000 are being processed every time my application is run. If I had 10,000 documents left to process, only ~400 are being processed every time my application is run.

Here is the code that I am dealing with: http://pastebin.com/EATpyNrp - I'd post it inline in this question, but it's hard to simplify it much further.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'll send a beer/pizza to anyone who can help me find a solution.

Thanks!